# Comparison between two integrals for positive decreasing functions.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $1<q<p<\infty$ and $f$ be any function from the set of non-negative and non-increaing measurable functions on $[0, \infty)$ (let's call this set S). Consider the two integrals $A=\int_0^{\infty} f^p dx$ and $B=\int_0^{\infty} x^{\frac{q}{p}-1}f^q dx$. It is well known that if B converges, then so does A. My question is, can I get a function from S for which A converges but not B?

Comment: Maybe if you look at a proof of the "well-known" result, this will give you some ideas how to disprove the converse implication.

Comment: The proof uses a Hardy inequality for decreasing functions. I couldn't get any idea from that.